# How to give an "argument" to my function in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Python 2.7 and Tkinter. I am trying to make a button change its own text when clicked. The code seems correct, but I keep encountering this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: doStuff takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Here is my code:

```
def doStuff(event):
    button01.configure(command=doStuff2)
    button01.configure(text="Click me again!")

button01 = Button(root, text="Click me", command=doStuff)
button01.grid(row=8, column=6)
```

Where am I screwing up and how do I pass the needed argument to `doStuff()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the function as taking an `event`. What for? Have you also bound it to a keyboard key? A keyboard key, when pressed, will pass an event to whatever function it's bound to. However, the `Button` widget does not. If this function is only connected to that `Button`, simply remove the `event` from the function definition.

If you have bound the function to both this `Button` and a keyboard key (or mouse action, or something else that generates an event), give it a default argument with `def doStuff(event=None):`.